# cakephp find('all') get the last matched record

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

[image]

Hi all
i am want perform $this->Model->find('all'); on the broadcasts table where i have to fetch only the last broadcast id of each model like 4 for model 12 and 6 for model 13.i have done this by using a simple mysql query as below.

SELECT * FROM `broadcasts` WHERE id IN(SELECT MAX(id) FROM `broadcasts` GROUP BY `model_id`);

But i want to know how to implement this in cakephp.

Please give your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 6):

> Mysql query
>     you should use mysql query for getting record
>     The query is

```
SELECT max(id),model_id FROM `model` group by model_id
```

### Output

[image]

### Cakephp find query

```
<?php
  $data=$this->Brodcast->find('all',
    'fields' => array('MAX(id) AS maxid', 'model_id'), 
    'group'=>'model_id'
    );
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You should try rewriting your query to:-

```
$options['fields'] = array( 'MAX(id) AS maxid', 'model_id' );
$options['group'] = array( 'model_id' );
$this->ModelName->find( 'all', $options );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This it will work fine :-

```
<?php
      $data=$this->Brodcast->find('all',
        'fields' => array('MAX(id) AS maxid', 'model_id'), 
        'group'=>'model_id'
        );
      ?>
```